# How to compare 2 lists based on separate keys and output a new list with differences

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<Ap21Stock>` where by Ap21Stock looks like this:

```
public class Ap21Stock
{
    public Ap21Product Product { get; set; }
    public int FreeStock { get; set; }
}
```

with Ap21Product looking like:

```
public class Ap21Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StyleCode { get; set; }
    public string ColourCode { get; set; }
    public string SizeCode { get; set; }
}
```

I also have another `List<Product>` that looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public string SellerSku { get; set; }
    public string ShopSku { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int FulfillmentByNonSellable { get; set; }
}
```

I need to produce a separate list:
- The key of the first list is the concatenation of StyleCode, ColourCode and SizeCode separated by a period (.). This matches up to the `SellerSku` property in the second list.
- Only output values where `FreeStock` != `Quantity`.

Basically, I have 2 stock lists from separate system and need to lookup the differences, however both are keyed differently (first is keyed in separate fields whereas the second is one field keyed in a single string).

How would I do this?
I tried the below but it doesn't feel right (and possibly wrong and inefficient as I am getting zero results in my last dictionary which I haven't yet looked into):

```
        Dictionary<string, int> apparel21StocksKeyed = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach ( var product in apparel21Stocks )
        {
            apparel21StocksKeyed.Add(string.Concat(product.StyleCode, ".", product.ColourCode, ".", product.SizeCode, "."), product.FreeStock);
        }

        //loop over the products, producing a list to send back to The Iconic
        Dictionary<string, int> productsToUpdate = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach  (var stock in iconicStocks)
        {
            if (apparel21StocksKeyed.ContainsKey(stock.SellerSku) && apparel21StocksKeyed[stock.SellerSku] != stock.Quantity)
            {
                productsToUpdate.Add(stock.SellerSku, apparel21StocksKeyed[stock.SellerSku]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Ap21Stock> stock = new List<Ap21Stock>();
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

            var results = from s in stock
                          join p in products on string.Join(".", new string[] { s.ProductId.ToString(), s.StyleCode, s.ColourCode }) equals p.SellerSku
                          where s.FreeStock != p.Quantity 
                          select new { id = s.ProductId, sku = p.SellerSku };

        }
    }
    public class Ap21Stock
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string StyleCode { get; set; }
        public string ColourCode { get; set; }
        public string SizeCode { get; set; }
        public int FreeStock { get; set; }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public string SellerSku { get; set; }
        public string ShopSku { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int FulfillmentByNonSellable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've just made a change to my initial question as I've refactored the first object a bit, with the Product information now in a separate object on the Ap21Stock object.

Comment: Hi. This is missing the bit about comparing the quantity of the two objects. I'm guessing that will be a where on the linq?

Comment: Added quantity comparison.